# Deleting query in a SQL query without using types

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have created two tables, one has primitive types:

```
CREATE TABLE CARDS_BAD (
suit CHAR(1),
rank VARCHAR(2)
);
```

and the other one has a user defined types

```
CREATE TYPE suits AS ENUM ('♣', '♠', '♥', '♦');     
CREATE TYPE ranks AS ENUM ('2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'J', 'Q', 'K', '10', 'A');

CREATE TABLE CARDS_GOOD (
suit suits,
rank ranks
);
```

as you can see, the two tables would contain cards decks of poker, cards are added using a simple `INSERT` query. When I try to delete all the cards with rank 7 or lower from the two tables:

```
DELETE FROM cards_bad t where t.rank < '7';
DELETE FROM cards_good t where t.rank < '7';
```

the query works correctly on `cards_good` but also deletes cards with rank `10` in `cards_bad`, but i expected the result to be the same. Can someone explain to me why it's different? Also let's say I want to `INSERT` a `JOKER` card into decks (which has a rank Jo but no suit), why doesn't this work?

Comment: why ranks as varchar? not int? If you'll keep int it will solve your problem. When you'll compare string '7' > '10' then it return true.

Answer (score 2):

There is a sensible difference between the tables: `cards_good` relies on an enum type to store the `rank`s, while `cards_bads` uses `varchar()`.

When doing string comparison, `'10' < '7'`, because `'10'` starts with `'1'`, which is smaller than `'7'`.

On the other hand, while comparing `enum`s seems to work in your use case, I don't that it is guaranteed to work consistently.

A probably safer option would be to create a lookup table that explicitly assigns a (numeric) weight to each `rank`.

---

On the joker card, that *has a rank, but no suit*: as far as concerns, `suit` is not a mandatory column in your table, so nothing should prevent you from inserting that card with a `suit` set to `null`.